# CScrollView OnDraw not called

Tags: view, mfc, activex, draw

I have a class which is derived from CScrollView, and I have inherited OnDraw method. The OnDraw method is not getting called unless until I do resize. Any special properties needs to be set or any way to trigger OnDraw method with out doing resize?

Answer (score 0):

You require two function calls.
1) Invalidate or InvalidateRect
2) UpdateWindow

The Invalidate function will mark your entire view as update required (redrawn)
The InvalidateRect is useful to mark portion of your view as update required.

Once you call update window, the entire view is updated if you previously called Invalidate or all the marked portions of the windows will be redrawn if you previous made one or more calls to the InvalidateRect.

Comment: I tried invalidateRect and UpdateWindow. Still OnDraw method not gets called. Its called only when Resize happens.